# jest.doMock and JSON import mocking

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I have such code to test:

```
...
import data from '../data/mock.json';

// function is async
export const something = async () => {
    try {
        ...
        if (!data) {
          throw 'error is here!';
        }

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
};
```

and my spec looks so:

```
...
import { something } from './handler';

describe('handler: something', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules();
    });

    describe('on something', () => {
        it('should return data', async () => {
            const data = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    price: '1',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    price: '2',
                },
            ];

            jest.doMock('../data/mock.json', () => {
                return {
                    __esModule: true,
                    default: data,
                };
            });
            await import('../data/mock.json');

            await expect(something()).resolves.toEqual(data);
        });

        it('should return error', async () => {
            jest.doMock('../data/mock.json', () => ({
                __esModule: true,
                default: undefined,
            }));

            await import('../data/mock.json');

            await expect(something()).resolves.toBe('error is here');
        });
    });
});
```

not sure why: but it doesn't mock json import inside my code, that I wish to test. What I do wrong and how to make this import mocked 'conditionally'? because if I mock it at the top of the file (nearby imports) - it will work but will be the same for all test cases while I need to make this data different in different test cases.

Comment: Because that's how the mocking works. If it's not been done when the module under test gets loaded, the module under test doesn't see the mock. Jest hoists this if it's in the top-level scope, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports, but not it it's inside a test suite or function. Try splitting out the JSON loading from your other logic, put it behind a facade e.g. `getData()` in another module that's easier to mock.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon how do you mean?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, from the docs `doMock` is used exactly for the my case, fixing hoisting etc. How do you mean?

Comment: `something` isn't shown so it's likely imported once on top level. It's `something`, not mock.json that should be reimported in tests.

Comment: `doMock` *avoids* hoisting; you're dynamically re-importing the JSON file but *not* the module that you're testing, so it still has the original reference. How do I mean what?

Comment: > but not the module that you're testing - is it possible to fix it somehow, except creating a facade? :)

Comment: @EstusFlask it's shown in the example.

Comment: There's no `something` in tests. I suppose that import section was omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jest.doMock` cannot affect `something` because it already uses original `mock.json` and needs to be reimported, while reimporting `mock.json` in tests cannot affect anything on its own.

It should be:

```
    jest.doMock('../data/mock.json', () => ({
        __esModule: true,
        default: undefined,
    }));

    const { something } = await import('./handler');

    await expect(something()).resolves.toBe('error is here');
```

Comment: ah, yes... import is like this: `import { something } from './handler';`

Comment: I see. So it should be named import that is local to the test.

Comment: Was a bit hard to understand since I did not realize at first that './handler' is the file where the json gets imported. Found a working solution for my related problem though with the dynamic import.